# Program to scan ASP.NET projects or IIS 6 site and show bad links?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, hyperlink

I've looked around and haven't had much luck locating a program that will search a site for bad / broken links.

We have IIS 6 so I can't use Microsoft's IIS 7 SEO offering which supposedly will do that.

We use forms auth so I need something that will allow me to store the user/pass stuff needed to navigate past the login page.

Many of our links are pulled from the database and rendered to the page so we want to include this as part of our QA process before deploying changes to live.

Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the IIS7 SEO tool as long as you install it on a separate box.  I've done that so I can test my sites.

Comment: Did not know that, thank you!  Though if anyone has any other suggestions for 3rd party tools I am still very interested in those as well.